# VPN Service. The packets are not passing through the tunnel

Tags: android, vpn

When the code is executed in an **Emulator** and when I start service and browse a site in browser app and it cant reach the site and it show me `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`.

Please tell me the problem where it has gone wrong.

```
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(
   mInterface.getFileDescriptor());
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(
   mInterface.getFileDescriptor());
DatagramChannel tunnel = DatagramChannel.open();
tunnel.connect(new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 8087));
Log.e("Localhost:",InetAddress.getLocalHost().toString());
protect(tunnel.socket());
Log.e("MyVpnJavaClass", "protected tunnel");
ByteBuffer packet = ByteBuffer.allocate(32767);
Log.e("MyVpnJavaClass", "Byte Buffer packets");
int timer = 0;
Thread.sleep(100);
```

The above code works fine as `LOGCAT` displays till "BYTE BUFFER PACKETS". But in the while Loop it does not show all the `LOGCAT` messages. Please rectify me the problem

```
while(true) {
    Log.e("MyVpnJavaClass", "while is true");
    boolean idle = true;
    int length = in.read(packet.array());
    if (length > 0) {
    Log.e("MyVpnJavaClass", "Lenght is > 0");
    packet.limit(length);
    Log.e("MyVpnJavaClass", "LIMITING Lenght");
    DatagramPacket datagramPacket = new DatagramPacket(packet.array(),packet.array().length);
    byte[] dataInThePacket = datagramPacket.getData();

    System.out.println(DatagramSocketService.stringFromPacket(datagramPacket));
    Log.e("MyVpnJavaClass", "system");

    TCPPacket tcpPacket = new TCPPacket(0,packet.array());
    int sourcePort = tcpPacket.getSourcePort();
    String destAddress = tcpPacket.getDestinationAddress();
    int destPort = tcpPacket.getDestinationPort();

    Log.e("MyVpnJavaClass", "TCPPacket");
    datagramPacket.setSocketAddress(new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 8087));
    Log.e("MyVpnJavaClass", "datagram packet");

    UDPPacket udpPacket = new UDPPacket(0, packet.array());

    System.out.println("TCP Source port: " + );
    System.out.println("TCP Destination port: " + );
    System.out.println("TCP Destination address: " +);
    System.out.println("Length of data: " + );

    Log.e("MyVpnJavaClass", "System out commands");

    System.out.println(" ");

    System.out.println("UDPPacket destination address: " +);
    System.out.println("UDPPacket destination port: " +);
    System.out.println("IP Protocol: " + );
    System.out.println("Length of data: " + );
    Log.e("MyVpnJavaClass", "UDP Packets");

    tunnel.write(packet);
    packet.clear();
    Log.e("MyVpnJavaClass", "Write & Clear");

    idle = false;

    if (timer < 1) {
          timer = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? I am having a similar problem(:

Answer (score -1):

Try checking one part of the program at a time.
Even I am working on a similar project and had a similar problem.
I tried writing tunnel.write() immediately after in.read and it worked. 
I searched for why its happening but didn't get any answers